# Could "AutoResetEven's Waitone()" create hurdle in stopping a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

In my windows service, I start 5 independently working threads, which do not write common resources (so no mutex or deadlock).

But one thread has a `AutoResetEvent`  `_waitTillUSBInsterted.WaitOne()` call. Basically, this thread is responsible for starting USB file transfer as soon as the USB is inserted and therefore it waits till it receives a notifying signal (by setting `_waitTillUSBInsterted` i.e. by calling `_waitTillUSBInsterted.Set()`) from the thread which is responsible for monitoring USB insertion/removal events.

**QUESTION:** Could it be possible that because of `_waitTillUSBInsterted.WaitOne()`, my windows service won't stop?

**Reason for Asking:** I tried to stop the windows service through the windows service manager tool (by pressing "stop") and it couldn't stop the service (got ***Error 1053***). I finally had to restart my PC. It happened again and again (4-5 times). I commented out all the threads-starting calls and then ***I was able to stop my windows service.*** I uncommented all threads-starting calls one by one but now I am able to stop the windows service (without making any changes). I am not able to reproduce the condition but I doubt `_waitTillUSBInsterted.WaitOne()` could be the reason.

Comment: It is up to you to define what the stop state means.  But surely you ought to use WaitAny() so the thread can also complete when the user stops the service.  It is not strictly necessary, you could also simply ignore the USB insertion or not use the USB device when the service is not active.

Comment: Do you have ANYTHING at all in the OnStop event?

Answer (score 0):

If your thread is a foreground thread and you do not use EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32) then yes: the thread is a foreground thread which prevents the process from terminating until the thread has terminated and WaitOne() blocks the thread, preventing it from terminating.

From [System.Threading.Thread.IsBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete. By default, the following threads
>   execute in the foreground (that is, their IsBackground property
>   returns false):
>
> - The primary thread (or main application thread).
> - All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor.
>
> Any thread that is created by use of a Thread constructor, unless
>   specifically configured by use of the IsBackground property, will be a
>   foreground thread and will prevent termination of the process until it
>   is terminated.

From [System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a
>   signal.

There are a couple of ways to alleviate the problem.
First: if you can stand the thread terminating prematurely then construct the thread like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(ThreadStart)
{
    IsBackground = true
}
```

When the service terminates the process will exit properly despite the fact that the thread is blocking on a WaitHandle.WaitOne() call.

The second way is to use some sort of state, passed by reference, to inform the thread that it should terminate. The following example uses a CancellationToken.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

public class ServiceState
{
    public ServiceState(CancellationToken cancellationToken, WaitHandle waitHandle)
    {
        this.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        this.WaitHandle = waitHandle;
    }

    public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; }

    public WaitHandle WaitHandle { get; }
}

public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly Thread serviceThread;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private readonly WaitHandle waitHandle;

    public Service()
    {
        serviceThread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var state = new ServiceState(cancellationTokenSource.Token, waitHandle);
        serviceThread.Start(state);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        waitHandle.Set();
    }

    private static void ThreadProc(object state)
    {
        var serviceState = (ServiceState)state;

        do
        {
            serviceState.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
            if (serviceState.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return; // This will terminate the thread.
            }

            // Thread logic goes here.
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThingyWotsit A service in Windows is nothing more than an executable that is launched in a special context (the service control manager). Since the service in question is a .NET executable we gain the benefits and implications of the .NET runtime, including managed threads, which follow the rules that I referenced in the answer (foreground vs. background).
In the context of foreground vs. background threads the difference is that one (foreground) will prevent a process from terminating while the other (background) will not.

Comment: OK - default must be background, then, (else my C# services would be in trouble:).

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the primary thread as well as threads created via new Thread() are foreground unless you explicitly set IsBackground to true. If you are using a thread pool those threads would all be background threads.